# Run SQL Files If Changed or Run New SQL Files in Folder with Liquibase

Tags: sql, mariadb, liquibase

I have a sql folder and sql files in this folder.

I want to run every changes in this folder.
For example: if new sql file is added on sql folder, I want to run it or if new lines are added to one of the files in this folder, I want to run only new lines. Is there any possibility to make this with Liquibase ?

Here is my changelog xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
             http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

        <changeSet id="1359722450-38" author="garip" runOnChange="true">
            <sqlFile endDelimiter="" splitStatements="false" path="../sql/sql1.sql"
                relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
        </changeSet>

    </databaseChangeLog>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The place where you will have problems is the request

> ...or if new lines are added to one of the files in this folder, I want
>   to run only new lines.

Liquibase will only run an entire SQL script. In order to just run the 'new' lines it would have to parse and understand all the different SQL dialects, which Liquibase does not do.

Answer (score 1):

Try to combine Liquibase without changelogs (http://www.liquibase.org/2015/09/liquibase-without-changelogs.html) and runOnChange option (http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changeset.html), but "if new lines are added to one of the files in this folder, I want to run only new lines" is not possible - you can run only the whole file if it is changed.